# jquery script on html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, bottle

I'm using [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html) to make a simple web form and want to set the [Selectize.js](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/) jquery plugin to a field so the user can set several values to that same field.
Inside my form tag I have the following code:

```
<label>
    <span>Links :</span>
    <input type="text" id="input-tags" name="links">
</label>
<script>
$('#input-tags').selectize({
    persist: false,
    createOnBlur: true,
    create: true
});
</script>
```

And the following .js and .css inside the head tag:

```
<link href="/selectize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/selectize.js"></script>
```

To deal with static files I have the following route in my .py script:

```
@get('/<filename:re:.*\.js>')
def javascripts(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='static/js')

@get('/<filename:re:.*\.css>')
def stylesheets(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='static/css')
```

My route to deal with static files seems to be working properly 'cause I've tested it with other jquery plugin that does not use explicit code within the html file.

On this one, the problem seems to be on the explicit script code bellow the label tag. I found some articles about dealing with JSON but couldn't make it work (I also don't know if that is the right way to go).

Comment: you just need a ready() function to wait for jq

Comment: I've tried to add explicit jq script within the ready() function no sucess
$( document ).ready(function() {
    <my script>
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my best option was to put that explicit javascript into a new javascript file and add its path to the html like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/<script_path_here>"></script>
```

That way my functions that handles the static files on the .py would do their job.